# I recently have installed Ubuntu 12.10 onto my computer

Tags: boot, nautilus, 12.10

yes, the title says it all. but there are problems. when I start the computer, Ubuntu boots properly, and takes me to the log in screen, however, once I've logged in and am taken to my desktop, there is nothing except the default wallpaper and my mouse. there is no unity sidebar, nor title bar. I can right click and access that particular menu, but that's it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No menu bar after upgrading to 12.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203523/no-menu-bar-after-upgrading-to-12-10)

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with your install that doesn't require a fix.

I recommend going and remaking the boot-able USB, before that, try to see if you can open up terminal to execute commands, Press Ctrl +alt+T. If it doesn't there's a serious problem with the install, try to install it again off the same boot-able USB you made for this Ubuntu, and see if that fixes the problem. If not, just remake a new boot-able USB then re-install from there.